# Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.4.1 Relay Access Denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtp

I am getting "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.4.1 Unable to relay for myemail@mydomain.com" when I try to send the mail using C# code.

Then I tested my smtp server [here](https://www.wormly.com/test_smtp_server).

Here when I enter my smtp server, sender and recipient name. I got followoing message:

> MAIL FROM: mymail@mydomain.com
>
> SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
>
> 250 2.1.0 Sender OK
>
> RCPT TO: anothermail@mydomain.com
>
> SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
>
> 550 5.4.1 Relay Access Denied
>
> SMTP -> ERROR: RCPT not accepted from server: 550 5.4.1 Relay Access
>   Denied

Message sending failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a config issue in the mail servier. It doesn't allow you (your IP, your sender address) to send mail to the recipient.

A properly configured mail server is extremely restrictive with relaying, to prevent it from being abused by spammers to send mails.

Comment: The Admin needs to configure the IP on the SMTP Server to allow for mails to be relayed from it

Comment: so, @Anders Abel, its not a config issue in the mail server, but can we say, its a restriction imposed on the mail server? I mean, if they intend to have no other users use any other tools or smtp to send email via this email server but only by specific user account/service-accounts?

Comment: how to configure the IP on the SMTP Server to allow for mails to be relayed from it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a Mail Server Configuration issue. We need to change few code for this. Can you please see my answer from below URL.

**URL:** [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979135/the-server-rejected-one-or-more-recipient-addresses-the-server-response-was-550/16975532#16975532)